# Pusher on leave page execute client trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, pusher

I'm unable to trigger a Pusher Client event when the user leaves the page. It does not trigger at all.

```
$(window).on('unload', function()
{
    MyPusher.presenceChannel.trigger('client-users', { id: MyPusher.user_id, name: MyPusher.user_name });
});
```

I know this trigger works because I use it in a button, but when leaving the page nothing gets executed. The Debug Console in [www.pusher.com](https://pusher.com) does not show the trigger being executed (while it does in a button).

Comment: Do you know if the Pusher connection is still available at the time your code is invoked? If the connection has already been destroyed then the event will fail to send. 

If you are looking for ways to track whether a user is online or offline with Pusher Channels then you might benefit from using their Presence channels, designed for this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `pusher:member_removed` event.

```
MyPusher.presenceChannel.bind('pusher:member_removed', function(member)
{
   MyPusher.presenceChannel.trigger('client-users', { id: MyPusher.user_id, name: MyPusher.user_name });
});
```